# How can I diff two XML files?

Tags: linux, xml, diff

On Linux, how could I generate a diff between two XML files?

Ideally, I would like to be able configure it to some things strict, or loosen some things, like whitespace, or attribute order.

I'll often care that the files are functionally the same, but diff by itself, would be annoying to use, especially if the XML file doesn't have a lot of linebreaks.

For example, the following should really be okay to me:

```
<tag att1="one" att2="two">
  content
</tag>

<tag att2="two" att1="one">
  content
</tag>
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

One approach would be to first turn both XML files into [Canonical XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML), and compare the results using `diff`.  For example, [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) can be used to canonicalize XML.

```
$ xmllint --c14n one.xml > 1.xml
$ xmllint --c14n two.xml > 2.xml
$ diff 1.xml 2.xml
```

Or as a one-liner.

```
$ diff <(xmllint --c14n one.xml) <(xmllint --c14n two.xml)
```

Comment: Never knew about the --c14n switch in xmllint. That's handy.

Comment: You can do it in one line too `vimdiff <(xmllint --c14n one.xml) <(xmllint --c14n two.xml)`

Comment: and xmllint ships with OS X

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, c14n is an abbreviation for _canonicalization_.

Comment: It is better to execute an additional step before diff - formatting of both XMLs (xmllint --format). Because I've noticed that without this step diff shows more differences than necessary.

Comment: another run with `xmllint --format` may be helpful (see other answers)

Comment: I have machine-output xml files to compare manually and tried `--format` to decrease my effort but it actually had trouble with indenting and increased the output size. This is libxml2-utils version  2.9.4+dfsg1-7+deb10u2 amd64 - maybe newer versions don't trip on this.

Comment: I also needed `XMLLINT_INDENT="  " xmllint --format ...` because --c14n does NOT unify tabs versus spaces at the beginning of the lines, thus the files where still different.

Answer (score 34):

Jukka's answer did not work for me, but it did point to Canonical XML.   Neither *--c14n* nor *--c14n11* sorted the attributes, but i did find the ***--exc-c14n*** switch did sort the attributes.  ***--exc-c14n*** is not listed in the man page, but described on the command line as "W3C exclusive canonical format".

```
$ xmllint --exc-c14n one.xml > 1.xml
$ xmllint --exc-c14n two.xml > 2.xml
$ diff 1.xml 2.xml

$ xmllint | grep c14
    --c14n : save in W3C canonical format v1.0 (with comments)
    --c14n11 : save in W3C canonical format v1.1 (with comments)
    --exc-c14n : save in W3C exclusive canonical format (with comments)

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/xmllint
libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64
libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6.i686

$ cat /etc/system-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Warning ***--exc-c14n***  strips out the xml header whereas the --c14n prepends the xml header if not there.

Answer (score 23):

Tried to use @Jukka Matilainen's answer but had problems with white-space (one of the files was a huge one-liner).
Using `--format` helps to skip white-space differences.

```
xmllint --format one.xml > 1.xml  
xmllint --format two.xml > 2.xml  
diff 1.xml 2.xml
```

Note: Use `vimdiff` command for side-by-side comparison of the xmls.

Comment: In my case `two.xml` was generated from `one.xml` by a script. So I just needed to check what was added/removed by the script.

Comment: This was the option I needed. Supposedly the most canonical version can be obtained by combining `--format` with `--exc-c14n`; will probably be still slower to process :(

Comment: It's been quite some time since I wrote the answer, but I faintly remember using the --exc-c14n flag. However, diff-ing the output with/without the flag showed no differences so just stopped using it. Dropping unnecessary/unused flags might make the process faster.

Comment: The `--exc-c14n` option specifies sorting of the attributes. In your specific files the attributes probably were already sorted, but the general advice would be to use the combination `--format --exc-c14n`.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to also ignore the order of child elements, I wrote a simple python tool for this called `xmldiffs`:

> Compare two XML files, ignoring element and attribute order.
>
> Usage: `xmldiffs [OPTION] FILE1 FILE2`
>
> Any extra options are passed to the `diff` command.

Get it at https://github.com/joh/xmldiffs

Answer (score 7):

[Diffxml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/diffxml/) gets the basic functionality correct, though it doesn't seem to offer many options for configuration.

Edit: Project [Diffxml](https://github.com/amouat/diffxml) has been migrated to GitHub since 2013.

Comment: It's not quite there yet, but it looks promising at least.

Comment: not useful for large files though, died after eating 40GB (RAM + SWAP) when comparing two files ~20k lines each

Comment: note that project appears to be dead, with last update in 2013

Answer (score 1):

My Python script [xdiff.py](https://hg.sr.ht/~nolda/xdiff) for comparing XML files ignores differences in
whitespace or attribute order (in contrast to element order).

In order to compare two files `1.xml` and `2.xml`, you would run the script as follows:

```
xdiff.py 1.xml 2.xml
```

In the OP's example, it would output nothing and return exit status `0` (for no
structural or textual differences).

In cases where `1.xml` and `2.xml` differ structurally, it mimics the unified
output of GNU diff and returns exit status `1`. There are various options for controlling the output, such
as `-a` for outputting all context, `-n` for outputting no context, and `-q` for
suppressing output altogether (while still returning the exit status).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this and is a developer and knows programming languages, then you can also check XML difference using [XMLUnit](https://www.xmlunit.org/) in C# or JAVA.

For checking how does it show's difference you can try this [online XML difference checker tool](https://www.minify-beautify.com/online-xml-difference/)

C# Sample Code to check difference

```
string control = "<a><b attr=\"abc\"></b></a>";
string test = "<a><b attr=\"xyz\"></b></a>";

var myDiff = DiffBuilder.Compare(Input.FromString(control))
          .WithTest(Input.FromString(test))
          .Build();
          
Assert.IsFalse(myDiff.HasDifferences(), myDiff.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to compare all types of text based files. They produce versions for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Plain text comparisons would say the two lines differed, whereas the OP wants them to be reported as the same.

Comment: i.e. **Canonically compare** the XML.

Comment: Beyond Compare really sucks for this. It seems to just not be aware of XML elements and do mostly just text comparison.

Comment: Beyond Compare has an XML plugin but I was never able to install it properly, so... Nyeah... I came to this page and got wiser...

Answer (score -1):

Our [SD Smart Differencer](http://semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) compares documents based on *structure* as opposed to actual layout.

There's an XML Smart Differencer. For XML, that means matching order of tags and content. It should note that the text string in the specific fragment you indicated was different.  It presently doesn't understand the XML notion of tag attributes indicating whether
whitespace is normalized vs. significant.

Comment: In your SO profile you provide full disclosure about your employer; I'd have preferred a short disclaimer inside your answer as well :) BTW, I tried to download an evaluation copy, but the request form is 'smart' (via JS) enough to disable the combination XML with Smart Differencer (also the latter in combination with Python, although possible according to the SD product page)?

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for the reminder.  This is an answer from a time before there was a clear SO policy on this.  I'm revising the answer to signal the relationship in SO policy compliant answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether (the dependence of) an online tool counts as a solution but, for what it's worth, I got good result in this [online XML comparison tool](https://www.corefiling.com/opensource/xmldiff/). It simply works.