# How to configure BeyondCompare to mark newline differences as unimportant?

Tags: windows, diff, file-comparison, beyondcompare

Newline additions in the middle of a line in BeyondCompare are marked as important. I want them to become unimportant. How to do that?

Example:

A:

```
<img src="a.gif"/>
```

B:

```
<img 
     src="a.gif"/>
```

Comment: I found a solution here: [Answer to: Line-length-tolerant XML diff](https://superuser.com/a/522468/778440)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> Session Settings > Importance >
>   Compare line endings

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

Comment: doesn't work either