# Beyond-compare wont ignore line-breaks?

Tags: windows-7, text-editing, file-comparison, beyondcompare

I have this comparison :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZej7.jpg]

I want those line to be treated equal.

but it showes me they are different.

I already applied those settings :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2be9.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzjQa.jpg]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092538/how-to-ignore-line-breaks

> even if you're ignoring line breaks, it won't treat the non-ignored
>   text on separate lines as being continuous across line breaks.

Comment: you right. look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible

I got an email from the company itself :

> Sorry, it isn't possible to ignore line breaks.
>
> This means:
>
> one two
>
> and
>
> one
>   two
>
> will always show as differences.
>
> Comparison across line breaks is on our wish list for a future version
>   of Beyond Compare.
>
> Best Regards, Chris Kennedy Scooter Software

Comment: It would be especially useful for diffing xml, where the line break doesn't matter (ish).

Comment: @AlexKey http://superuser.com/a/522468/98191

Comment: Thanks @RoyiNamir I completely forgot about that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was also hoping that beyond compare would have something like this built in.  Looks like it doesn't.

The best solution I have found to do this is to use some kind of code formatter on both sides.  This allows you to compare real changes in the code.  For javascript, I use JSBeautify.

For Java you could probably use your editor's built in beautifier or something like this: http://prettyprinter.de/