# What Windows app can sort a huge XML file?

Tags: windows, xml, sorting

I have some enormous XML-based configuration files, with 125000 lines in them. The problem is that they are auto-generated by the system I use, and "child" tags are in a random order within their respective parent tag. This means that a diff comparison is impossible.

**I want to recursively sort all tags within a parent tag** by the value in `name=""`. Some parent tags only appear once and don't have a `name=""` parameter; these should be sorted by the `tag` name itself.

Once the files are sorted like this, they can be compared quite easily using normal tools. We are currently using *ExamXML* which can match unsorted XML files, but it fails because the files are too big.

Is there an application that can do this? (Windows much preferred; [Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/79920/is-there-any-diff-tool-for-xml-files/81036#81036) only as a last resort)

I do not want to dive into development or XSLT jobs. I am thinking that someone must have made a simple sorting tool like this already - I just can't find it using Google.

**Update:**
With help from this site, I created a small package that I want to share: [XML-Sorter_v0.4public.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/135090/XML-Sorter_v0.4public.zip)

**Update:** [Follow-up question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8267147/20571)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you don't want to dive into XSLT, but it's by far the easiest way of doing it. All it takes is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="(@name, name())[1]"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have no understanding of XSLT, but this looks like it automatically runs through the tag names so I don't have to enumerate them. That is a BIG advantage over other XSLT-based solutions I've seen in my searches! Given your example, can I just take this and run it, or how would I need to adapt it? How *do* I actually "run" an XSLT? In a browser? (XML noob speaking...)

Comment: How to run: I found [this somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1590085/20571) but I don't really understand the answers.