# How do I "run" an XSLT file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've received a great answer about sorting XML - I need to [use XSLT](https://superuser.com/questions/355115/what-windows-app-can-sort-a-huge-xml-file/355175#355175). But how do I actually do that? What software is required?

**What command or application do I need to start** to get a "converted" XML output file, given that I've got an XML file and an XSLT file as input?

I don't have any development environment installed; this is a regular office computer with WinXP+IE7.

**Update:**
With help from this site, I created a small package that I want to share: [XML-Sorter_v0.3.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/135090/XML-Sorter_v0.3.zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First decide whether you want to use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. XSLT 2.0 is a much richer language, and the only reason for preferring XSLT 1.0 is that it's supported in a wider range of environments (for example, in the browser).

Then decide what XSLT processor you want to use. There's a wide choice for XSLT 1.0; a rather narrower choice for XSLT 2.0.

Then look in the documentation for that XSLT processor to find out how to run it.

Given that you seem to be OK with running the transformation from the Windows command line, I would recommend using Saxon-HE, which you can get from http://saxon.sf.net/. You will need to install Java, and then you can run Saxon. The documentation is here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline

If you prefer a simple GUI interface, consider "Kernow for Saxon".

If you want a development environment with a nice editor and debugger, you will have to pay for it, but Stylus Studio and oXygen are both good value, and both give you a choice of XSLT engines.

Comment: Installing a development suite seems like overkill, but I've just downloaded the saxon jar file. That seems to do the trick - at least it generates an output file! Whether that file is correct, is not part of my question here. Thanks!!

Comment: The commandline documentation link is no longer valid.

Comment: @fixer1234: I took a stab at it.  (The Wayback Machine is a GOOD THING.)

Answer (score 2):

An XSLT Processor like [Xalan-J](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) for a command line solution. For a GUI editor/debugger you can use Eclipse, a tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/XSLT/article.html).

Edit: A fully web-based solution [found here](http://www.purplegene.com/static/transform.html)

Comment: The web-based solution link was a nice edit.

Comment: The web-based solution no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have powershell available, and the XML file, and the XSLT file

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Transform an xml file
.DESCRIPTION
    load a XML file and load a XSLT file, then transform the XML using the XSLT and output to the console
.PARAMETER $xsltfilename
    The path to the XSLT file
.PARAMETER $filename
    The path to the XML file to be transformed
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> 
    .\tranform.ps1 .\rgs_broke.xml .\fix_escalation.xslt > rgs_fixed.xml
.NOTES
    Author: Alex McCool
    Date:   Jan 17, 2017
#>

param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$xsltfilename, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$filename
)


function Load-Xml
{
param([string]$filename)

$content = Get-Content $filename

$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream

$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
$writer.Write("$content")
$writer.Flush()
$stream.position = 0

$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($stream)

return $xml
}

function Load-Xslt
{
param([string]$filename)

$content = Get-Content $filename

$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
$writer.Write("$content")
$writer.Flush()
$stream.position = 0

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::create($stream)
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$xslt.Load($reader)

return $xslt
}


$xml = Load-Xml($filename)
$xslt = Load-Xslt($xsltfilename)

$output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($output)


$arglist = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
$xslt.Transform($xml, $arglist, $output)

$output.position = 0
$transformed = [string]$reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()

write-output $transformed
```

and here's a gist in case it changes

https://gist.github.com/amccool/560b533f1ea94560e0dae6367c2b75ce